# Error while using LTXinputExample in frontmatter

Tags: front-matter, showexpl

When I use the command `LTXinputExample` from the package [showexpl](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/showexpl) at the `frontmatter` section of a book, I got the following error message: `Missing number, treated as zero. \LTXinputExample{input_example}`

I don't know what could this message be about.

inputExample file:

```
This an example file.
```

Main file:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{F}
% \lstinputlisting{inputExample}
\LTXinputExample{inputExample}
\mainmatter
\chapter{M}
\LTXinputExample{inputExample}
\end{document}
```

Strange enough, the results seem correct, despite always presenting a error.

[image]
[image]

On the other hand, there is no error when using `\lstinputlisting` from `listings` (which is also loaded by `showexpl`).

This is part of the `log` file:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   i
l.7 \LTXinputExample{inputExample}
                                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

(inputExample.tex)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 7.

--------------------------------
pos=l
width=172.5pt
hsep=10.0pt
vsep=12.0pt
overhang=0pt
rframe=single
codefile=inputExample
\if@SX@wide=FALSE
\if@SX@rangeaccept=FALSE
\if@SX@varwidth=FALSE
graphicfile=, graphicparameter=[width=\linewidth ]
--------------------------------
(inputExample.tex) [3] [4

]
```

Comment: `\LTXinputExample` tries to find out if it is on a odd or an even page, but for roman page numbering its code doesn't work as ` i ` is not a number ...

Comment: hmmm I see. I found at line 94 of `showexpl` `\ifodd\getpagerefnumber{\SX@IDENT}%`, any ideas to work this problem around?